# How to mask elements with padding in tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-lite

Given two example tensors `input` and `mask`:

```
>>> input = tf.random.normal([2,3,5])
>>> input
<tf.Tensor: shape=(2, 3, 5), dtype=float32, numpy=
array([[[ 1.1260294 , -0.05932725,  0.85893923, -1.5332409 ,
          0.6681451 ],
        [ 0.8833729 ,  0.8421117 , -0.60990584,  0.08593109,
          0.5969471 ],
        [ 0.20015325, -0.9459327 , -1.0818844 , -1.7254639 ,
         -0.51545954]],

       [[-0.36073774, -0.24315724,  1.5217028 ,  1.5075827 ,
          0.05745999],
        [-0.2570101 ,  1.5501927 , -0.17113225,  0.16063859,
         -0.95638955],
        [ 0.48955616,  0.11943919, -0.3523262 ,  0.10750653,
          1.1027677 ]]], dtype=float32)>

>>> mask = tf.constant([[0,1,0],[1,0,1]])
>>> mask
<tf.Tensor: shape=(2, 3), dtype=int32, numpy=
array([[0, 1, 0],
       [1, 0, 1]], dtype=int32)>
```

I need to mask out `input` according to `mask` where values are 0. However, since the number of masked out elements for each example in the batch `input` might be different, to keep the output a valid tensor, the output should be:

```
>>> masked_input
<tf.Tensor: shape=(2, 3, 5), dtype=float32, numpy=
array([[[ 0.8833729 ,  0.8421117 , -0.60990584,  0.08593109,
          0.5969471 ],
        [ 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 ,
         0],
        [ 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 ,
         0]],

       [[-0.36073774, -0.24315724,  1.5217028 ,  1.5075827 ,
          0.05745999],
        [ 0.48955616,  0.11943919, -0.3523262 ,  0.10750653,
          1.1027677 ],
        [ 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 ,
          0]]], dtype=float32)>
```

i.e. in the output, the masked input keeps only elements where `mask` is 1, and, with zero-padding at the end to ensure that the output is a valid tensor.

I've searched around and tried using:

1. `tf.gather`, however, still can't figure out how to proceed.
2. `tf.boolean_mask`, however, it doesn't support masking but just drops the first (zeroth) dimension, as shown below:

```
>>> tf.boolean_mask(input, mask)
<tf.Tensor: shape=(3, 5), dtype=float32, numpy=
array([[ 0.8833729 ,  0.8421117 , -0.60990584,  0.08593109,  0.5969471 ],
       [-0.36073774, -0.24315724,  1.5217028 ,  1.5075827 ,  0.05745999],
       [ 0.48955616,  0.11943919, -0.3523262 ,  0.10750653,  1.1027677 ]],
      dtype=float32)>
```

3. `tf.ragged.boolean_mask`, this is by far the closest one to what I want, it keeps the dimension, however, still doesn't support masking, so the result is a ragged tensor...

Similar issues are mentioned in GitHub: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/18238

In short:

```
tensor = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
mask = np.array([[True, False, True], [False, False, True], [True, True, True]])
boolean_mask(tensor, mask, keepdims=False) # [1, 3, 6, 7, 8, 9]
boolean_mask(tensor, mask, keepdims=True, pad_val=0) # [[1, 3, 0], [6, 0, 0], [7, 8, 9]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do by,

`inputs * tf.cast(mask[...,None], tf.float32)`